# MySQL understanding INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING

Tags: mysql, profiling, partition, information-schema

How to understand BLOCK_OPS_IN because [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-profiling-table.html) doesn't provide good understanding information
:

> BLOCK_OPS_IN: indicate the number of block input and output operations

```
+----------+-----+----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| QUERY_ID | SEQ | STATE                | DURATION   | CPU_USER   | CPU_SYSTEM | CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY | CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY | BLOCK_OPS_IN | BLOCK_OPS_OUT | MESSAGES_SENT | MESSAGES_RECEIVED | PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR | PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR | SWAPS | SOURCE_FUNCTION       | SOURCE_FILE          | SOURCE_LINE |
+----------+-----+----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|    58727 |   2 | starting             |   0.000067 |   0.000057 |   0.000010 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | NULL                  | NULL                 |        NULL |
|    58727 |   3 | checking permissions |   0.000009 |   0.000009 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_authorization.cc |         809 |
|    58727 |   4 | Opening tables       |   0.000017 |   0.000014 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc          |        5815 |
|    58727 |   5 | init                 |   0.000018 |   0.000015 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | handle_query          | sql_select.cc        |         128 |
|    58727 |   6 | System lock          |   0.000011 |   0.000009 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc              |         330 |
|    58727 |   7 | optimizing           |   0.000009 |   0.000008 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         158 |
|    58727 |   8 | statistics           |   0.000015 |   0.000013 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         374 |
|    58727 |   9 | preparing            |   0.000016 |   0.000013 |   0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc     |         482 |
|    58727 |  10 | Sorting result       |   0.000008 |   0.000005 |   0.000003 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | make_tmp_tables_info  | sql_select.cc        |        3849 |
|    58727 |  11 | executing            |   0.000006 |   0.000005 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec                  | sql_executor.cc      |         126 |
|    58727 |  12 | Sending data         | 227.947186 | 358.076440 |  74.617739 |           2907530 |              603751 |     12269736 |      36826856 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |              3214 |     0 | exec                  | sql_executor.cc      |         202 |
|    58727 |  13 | end                  |   0.000033 |   0.000026 |   0.000005 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | handle_query          | sql_select.cc        |         216 |
|    58727 |  14 | query end            |   0.014514 |   0.046292 |   0.005637 |               223 |                  43 |         1440 |          4424 |             0 |                 0 |                 2 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        4959 |
|    58727 |  15 | closing tables       |   0.000035 |   0.000029 |   0.000005 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc         |        5018 |
|    58727 |  16 | freeing items        |   0.000037 |   0.000063 |   0.000012 |                 1 |                   0 |            0 |            32 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_parse           | sql_parse.cc         |        5637 |
|    58727 |  17 | cleaning up          |   0.000018 |   0.000036 |   0.000007 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |            32 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc         |        1933 |
+----------+-----+----------------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

BLOCK_OPS_IN and BLOCK_OPS_OUT are very high in terms of millions, what does this value suggest how can we reduce it to make the MySQL run faster.

Comment: `Sending data` is an awful catchall -- It does not really tell you what is going on.

Comment: All the tools available merely try to tell you some of what is going on _now_.  You are asking for "what should be done _instead_".  Show me a query, and I can often answer that second question.  (But I don't know of a tool that will automate this.)

Comment: I find that the Handler counts better at showing I/O counts:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts